# XML Schema invalid content found with expected element

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XML schema fragment that goes like this:

```
<xsd:complexType name="CustomStreamHandlerConfig">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="AbstractStreamHandlerConfig">
            <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="class" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:group ref="CustomParameters" />
                    <xsd:group ref="NextElements" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                </xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="config-file" type="xsd:anyURI" />
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Basically, this schema allows an XML fragment to describe a `CustomStreamHandlerConfig` with some parameters (class, custom parameters, etc.) or with a configuration file URI.

The `CustomParameters` group allows a list of `single-params` elements in any number and a list of `multiple-params` in any number:

```
<xsd:group name="CustomParameters">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="single-params" type="KeyValue" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xsd:element name="multiple-params" type="KeyMultipleValues" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:group>
```

The `KeyValue` and `KeyMultipleValues` complex types go like this:

```
<xsd:complexType name="KeyValue">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:attribute name="key" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="KeyMultipleValues">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="value" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="key" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
</xsd:complexType>
```

When I try to assemble an XML fragment that represents a `CustomStreamHandlerConfig` :

```
<custom-stream-retriever>
    <class>MyCustomStreamHandler</class>
    <single-params key="single-key">single-value</single-params>
    <mutiple-params key="multiple-key"> <!-- Invalid content -->
        <value>multiple-value</value>
        <value>multiple-value</value>
    </mutiple-params>
</custom-stream-retriever>
```

I get an `cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'mutiple-params'.` error.

The thing is, when I inspect the list of expected elements, I find: `One of '{..., "SomeNamespace":multiple-params, ...}'  is expected.`

I compared `SomeNamespace` (example namespace name) to the `targetNamespace` in my schema file, and they are both the same. I must also precise that the `xsd:schema` tag has `elementFormDefault="qualified"`.

Why is the XML file refusing `mutiple-params` elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is a trick question, or a typo... your XSD describes a `multiple-params`, while your XML employs a `mutiple-params` - there's an l (lower case L) missing in the latter.

Comment: I'd say you are correct. The error says as much "found ... 'mutiple-params' ... expected multiple-params".

Comment: Yeah, that was it... My ctrl+space auto-complete in Eclipse must have been using a previous version of the XSD file because of a refresh issue.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see the spelling difference though... Thanks a lot guys!